# iOS Slow First Time Authentication Against ASP.NET Basic Service

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api, nsurlconnection

Does anyone else have an issue with slow initial authentication against ASP.NET Basic Service?

When my app logs in for the first time it takes around 3-4 seconds to auth against the server, after that it's pretty fast but this initial login time is disrupting users.

Does anyone else have this issue? If so, how did you resolve it? The service is using MVC4's WebAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and I found out that it was authenticating multiple times on the first connection.

In your willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge method, add this to see what kind of auths or how many it's performing when you do your first connection call.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod]);
```

I found that there were multiple auths like so:

```
2013-11-30 11:31:42.181 AppName[1529:70b] NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
2013-11-30 11:31:50.921 AppName[1529:70b] NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM
```

Only some of them actually needed auth credentials, a few of them could be skipped using code like this for "NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust"

```
if ([[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust){
    [[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

This sped it up a little for me. Also, moving to iOS7 sped it up quite a bit, since it moved some NSURLConnection handling into the OS. Other than that, I couldn't work with my server admins to relieve any of the extra security, maybe you have better luck.